# JavaScript Object vs Array in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

What is the difference between the JavaScript object in A vs that in B (see image). What are the extra fields in B?

Note:
Object A: I use $firebaseObject 
Object B: I use $firebaseArray

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `$firebaseObject` service takes a Firebase reference and **returns** a JavaScript **object** which contains the data at the provided Firebase reference and some extra AngularFire-specific fields.

The `$firebaseArray` service takes a Firebase reference and **returns** a JavaScript **array** which contains the data at the provided Firebase reference.

All this things was copied and pasted from the https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject